# What's the difference between "could you" and "will you" when you request someone to do something?

Tags: difference

[image]

> **Will you** get me a meeting with the head of NTSB?

I searched "difference will you could you", seems found nothing useful.

Comment: You can't search like that. You have to look up verb usages for will and could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Could you' is, strictly speaking, asking whether the person is capable or able to do something.

'Will you' has an implication that the person is capable of doing something, and is more of a request that they do, actually, do it (for you).

Answer (score 1):

- Will you please lend me your pen?
- Would you pleae lend me your pen?
- Could you please lend me your pen?

All of them are polite requests.

In general:

- *could you please* is more polite than *would you please*
- *would you please* is more polite than *will you please*
- *will you please* is polite but less polite than the other two

It depends on who you are asking: your friend, a teacher, a stranger or a police officer.

Comment: How about "*Can you please*"? Is it a bit too direct and impolite?